# Finding Similarities Between houses in pandas dataframe for content filtering

Tags: pandas, matrix, filtering, similarity

I want to apply content filtering for houses. I would like to find  similarity score for each houses  to recommend. What can I recommend for house one? So I need similarity matrix for houses. How can I find it?

Thank you

```
    data = [['house1',100,1500,'gas','3+1']
    ,['house2',120,2000,'gas','2+1']
    ,['house3',40,1600,'electricity','1+1']
    ,['house4',110,1450,'electricity','2+1']
    ,['house5',140,1200,'electricity','2+1']
    ,['house6',90,1000,'gas','3+1']
    ,['house7',110,1475,'gas','3+1']
   ]

     Create the pandas DataFrame 
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = 
    ['house','size','price','heating_type','room_count'])
```

Comment: you need to explain more. what do you mean by similarities. please explain and also add the expected output

Comment: thanks I edited to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we define similarity in terms of absolute difference in case of numeric values and similarity ratio calculated by `SequenceMatcher` in case of strings (or more presicely 1 - ratio to make it comparable to differences), we can apply these operations to the respective columns and then normalize the result to the range of 0 ... 1 where 1 means (almost) equality and 0 means minimum similarity. Summing up the individual columns, we get the most similar house as the house with the maximum total similarity rating.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

df = df.set_index('house')

res = pd.DataFrame(df[['size','price']].sub(df.loc['house1',['size','price']]).abs())
res['heating_type'] = df.heating_type.apply(lambda x: 1 - SequenceMatcher(None, df.heating_type[0], x).ratio())
res['room_count'] = df.room_count.apply(lambda x: 1 - SequenceMatcher(None, df.room_count[0], x).ratio())
res['total'] = res['size'] + res.price + res.heating_type + res.room_count
res = 1 - res / res.max()

print(res)
print('\nBest match of house1 is ' + res.total[1:].idxmax())
```

Result:

```
            size  price  heating_type  room_count     total
house                                                      
house1  1.000000   1.00           1.0         1.0  1.000000
house2  0.666667   0.00           1.0         0.0  0.000000
house3  0.000000   0.80           0.0         0.0  0.689942
house4  0.833333   0.90           0.0         0.0  0.882127
house5  0.333333   0.40           0.0         0.0  0.344010
house6  0.833333   0.00           1.0         1.0  0.019859
house7  0.833333   0.95           1.0         1.0  0.932735

Best match of house1 is house7
```